# Material UI Snackbar overlaps

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI Snackbar. I am not very new to Material UI but somehow I am unable to resolve the issue i.e., the snackbar is overlapping when it appears on top of the screen. I tried different ways to fix it but no luck.

Please find below Snackbar component and its body style. Also please find this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

```
bodyStyle:{
  border: "2px solid #ffffff",
  minWidth: '50%',
  maxWidth: '100%',
  flexGrow: 0,
  height:'55px',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  fontFamily: "Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif",
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 400,
  fontSize: 16
} 
snackbarfromTop: {
  top: 0,
  color: white,
  bottom: 'auto',
}

<Snackbar
        open={this.state.open}
        message={this.state.error}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        bodyStyle={myTheme.bodyStyle}
        action="Close"
        onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        onActionTouchTap={this.handleRequestClose}
        style={myTheme.snackbarfromTop}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using react and Material UI, when two snackbars where introduced, one was overlapping each other. I solved modifying the second child of the mui root snackbar in index.css

```
#root .MuiSnackbar-anchorOriginBottomCenter:nth-child(2){
    bottom: 92px!important;
}
```

It obviously depends upon which position you choose for the snackbar, and tweak accordingly

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot alone, I can't tell 100%, but it seems you have just made your `Snackbar` transparent with:

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

So you are actually seeing *through* it.

To fix this, you should specify a `backgroundColor` to your component, or remove the 'transparent' override, such as:

```
backgroundColor: '#bada55'
```

You might want to look at the [withStyles/withTheme HOC](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/) in order to declare your colors in one place and reuse them in different components, in which case you'll have something like this:

```
backgroundColor: theme.palette.my.predefined.color
```